# Error while trying to save input to SQL using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to input my details in MySQL using Java.
But I keep on having following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1

Here is my code:

```java
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
int vType;
System.out.println("Please enter Vehicle Type\n1 = Car\n2 = Van\n3 = Motorbike\n4 = Motorbike");
vType = input.nextInt();
if (vType==1){
    System.out.println("Car Brand: ");
    vehicle.setvBrand(input.next());
    System.out.println("Car License Plate: ");
    vehicle.setvLicense(input.next());
    try {
        Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        String parkCar = "INSERT INTO car_park_details(vehicle_brand, vehicle_license) values( ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement park = dbConn.prepareStatement(parkCar);
        park.executeUpdate(parkCar);
        park.setString(2,vehicle.getvBrand());
        park.setString(3, vehicle.getvLicense());
        park.execute();
        System.out.println("Try daw check sa DB MYONG!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? I'm a begginer Java Developer. thanks for the help.

Comment: You are attempting to execute the query twice, with different methods, and one of the execution is called before query parameters are set. Just remove this line from your code: `park.executeUpdate(parkCar);`

Comment: @GMB Not correct.  Call `park.executeUpdate()` with no parameters, and then delete the `park.execute()` line below it.

Comment: @GMB you’re right, just to add, preparedStatement.set starts from index 1. So update that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement park =       dbConn.prepareStatement(parkCar);   
park.setString(1, vehicle.getvBrand());
park.setString(2, vehicle.getvLicense());
park.executeUpdate();
```

PreparedStatement set parameters index starts from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below, i.e run `executeUpdate()` without parameters and only after you have set your parameters to the `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement park = dbConn.prepareStatement(parkCar);   
park.setString(1,vehicle.getvBrand());
park.setString(2, vehicle.getvLicense());
park.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The parameter indexes are incorrect here - they should be 1 and 2.